# Why does my programme runs sometimes, but take forever to run some other times?

Tags: java, netbeans

I was trying to make a program that would generate a [battleship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_(game)) board. It runs perfectly and generates a board sometimes, but at other times it keeps"run"ing. I was using netbeans on a mac, if that is helpful. (You might notice, that I did not invoke certain methods throughout my code, that is because this programme is not completed yet, it's halfway through) Here is my programme:

Class BattlehipGame:

```
public class BattleshipGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    gamemaker.shipMaker();
    }

}
```

Class gamemaker:

```
Public class gamemaker {
private static int numberOfShips;
 public static void numberOfShipsSetter(int shipNumber) 
 {
if (shipNumber<=5)
    {
        numberOfShips = shipNumber;
        gamemaker.shipMaker();
    }
 }

 public static void shipMaker()
 {
  ship aircraftCarrier = new ship();
  ship battleShip = new ship();
  ship cruiser = new ship();
  ship dest1 = new ship();
  ship dest2 = new ship();

  aircraftCarrier.sizeSetter(5);
 battleShip.sizeSetter(4);
 cruiser.sizeSetter(3);
 dest1.sizeSetter(2);
 dest2.sizeSetter(2);

 aircraftCarrier.OrientationSetter();
 battleShip.OrientationSetter();
 cruiser.OrientationSetter();
 dest1.OrientationSetter();
 dest2.OrientationSetter();

  aircraftCarrier.positionOfShip();
 battleShip.positionOfShip();
 cruiser.positionOfShip();
 dest1.positionOfShip();
 dest2.positionOfShip();

 for(int m=0; m<10; m++)
    {
        for(int g=0; g<10; g++)
    {
        System.out.print(position[g][m]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
    }





 }


}
```

Class ship:

```
public class ship {

 private int size;
 private int shipid = 0;
 private int orientationOfShip;
public static final int[][] position = new int[10][10];
 public void sizeSetter(int shipsize)
 {
 if (shipsize<=5)
 {
    size= shipsize;
    shipid=shipsize;
 }
 else
 {
     size =  0;
 }
 }


public void OrientationSetter()//this method sets whether the ship is vertical or horizontal (horizontal is 1, vertical is 2)
{
int orientation =  1 + (int)(Math.random()*2);
 orientationOfShip = orientation;
}

public void positionOfShip()//method gives the ship its position and updates the array/board
{
    Random randomno = new Random();
    if (orientationOfShip==1)//if orientation is horizontal
    {
        int i = 0;
        int xposition = randomno.nextInt(10-size);//this gives the x position of leftmost block of the ship  
        int yposition = randomno.nextInt(9);//this gives the y position of leftmost block of the ship

        boolean foo = false;

        do
        {
            while (foo==false&&i<size)
            {

                if (position[xposition+i][yposition]!=0||xposition+size>10)//checks if the ship hits another ship or has parts outside the "board"
                    {
                        foo = true;
                    }

                   i++;
            }


            if (foo)//if foo is true (i.e if it hits another ship/spills) then generate another position for the ship
                {

                        xposition = randomno.nextInt(9-size)+1;
                        yposition = randomno.nextInt(9)+1;

                }

        } while(foo);

        for (int bar = 0; bar<size; bar++)
        {
        position[xposition+bar][yposition] = shipid;
        }
    }


    else if (orientationOfShip==2)//this is the vertical version of the if
      {
        int i = 0;
        int ypos = randomno.nextInt(10-size);  
        int xpos = randomno.nextInt(9);

        boolean isThere = false;

        do
            {
                while (isThere==false&&i<size)
                    {
                        if (position[xpos][ypos+i]!=0||ypos+size>10)
                            {
                                isThere = true;
                            }
                        i++;
                    }
                if (isThere)
                    {            

                        ypos = randomno.nextInt(9-size)+1;
                        xpos = randomno.nextInt(9)+1;

                    }
        } while(isThere);

        for (int incVar = 0; incVar<size; incVar++)
        {
        position[xpos][ypos+incVar] = shipid;
        }
     }


}

}
```

Comment: You did not consider situation when there is no place for next ship. In this case it will try to place it forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In positionOfShip(), you need to set foo = false at the start of the outer do loop -- or if foo ever gets set to true, that outer loop will run forever.